# Javascript ternary operator (?:) change and return object in single block

Tags: javascript

Is it possible inside `?:` change dictionary and return this dictionary in the same block. Something like this `a > b ? <dict['c'] = 'I'm changed', return dict> : <some other code>;`

I need this inside `map` function. Something like this:

```
var a = [...]
a.map((itm) => return itm.isComposite ? itm[key] = transform(itm[data]); return itm : transform(itm))
```

Comment: It does not make sense to return from a ternary. Maybe show the actual code.

Comment: added real life case

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, it's possible** by using the [**comma operator**](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2015/11/17/the-comma-operator-in-javascript):

```
a > b ? (dict['c'] = "I'm changed", dict) : <some other code>;
```

The comma operator evaluates all of its operands and returns the value of the last (rightmost) one.

---

However, a proper `if` statement might be the more readable solution here, which is why I'd recommend you use it instead of constructing a conditional ("ternary") expression.

Answer (score 2):

The comma operator should be enough. No need to use the `return` keyword.

```
var result = (a > b
  ? (dict['c'] = "I'm changed", dict)
  : <some other code> );
```

If you want to return the result then it goes outside the expression:

```
return (a > b
  ? (dict['c'] = "I'm changed", dict)
  : <some other code> );
```

That said, I would prefer using if statements for this problem. In my opinion, long ternary expressions are hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

This can be shortened with the ?: like so:

```
var result = a > b ? methodOne() : methodTwo();
```

methodOne() and methodTwo() can return the result.

hope this will help you.

Comment: the purpose of having such construction is writing less code. I think implement 2 additional methods could be more readable, but much more work. So not sure it fit there

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
a > b ? (d) => {d['c'] = 'I'm changed'; return dict;}(dict): <some other code>;
```

> > `>> var d = {};`
> >
> > `>> 2 < 3 ? ((d) => {d.a =2; return d;}) (d) : 5;`
> >
> > `>> Object {a: 2}`